# How do I use AWS security groups to whitelist only certain EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2

My understanding of AWS Security Groups is that it is essentially a whitelist.

Everything is blocked unless explicitly allowed.

Let's say hypothetically that I have some EC2 instances setup with autoscaling.

In the context of autoscaling, I won't necessarily know what those future IP's will be.

Say I have a set of EC2 instances that are used for databases like mysql or mongodb.

I want to only allow my application servers to be able to access my database servers.

Is there a way to create a tag for an EC2 instance and per the security group, allow any EC2 instance with a certain tag?

How is this usually done in the real world?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you can use security groups as classifiers and use the security group 'id' for the 'Source' field.

For example:

Say you had a cluster of web servers who belong to a 'web' security group (sg-12345)

Say you had a cluster of database servers who belong to a 'db' security group (sg-23456)

You can have the 'db' security group allow port 3306 to sg-12345 and as long as new instances are brought up in the 'web' security group, they'll have access to 'db' on the port 3306

Comment: Does this work properly? I was never able to get this (allowing access to certain security groups) to work right.

Comment: For the sg-XXXXXX notation to work, you need to make the access via the servers private aws ip. (IE. not a public elastic ip).  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=414060

Comment: You can also use the public dns hostnames.

Comment: Above thing will work only when you access these instances via their public host-name OR via their private ip address. This will not work when you explicitly use the public IP address of the instances.